# Why is a templatized copy constructor not called?

Tags: c++, templates

Why is it that the following code fails to compile (complains about deleted copy constructor):

```
struct C {
    int i;
    
    C(const C&) = delete;
    C(int i) : i(i) {}
    
    template <typename T>
    C(const T& value) {
      cout << "in templatized constructor!\n";
      this->i = value.i * 2;
    }

};

int main()
{
   C s1{4};
   C s2{s1};

   cout << s2.i;
}
```

But when i remove the `const` from the templatized copy constructor, everything works:

```
    template <typename T>
    C(T& value) {
      cout << "in templatized constructor!\n";
      this->i = value.i * 2;
    }
```

Two questions:

(1) Why isn't the template contructor used as a fall-back when the generated copy constructor is deleted?

(2) Even though "templates can't be copy constructors" - how/why is it that the  C(T&); constructor IS being used as a copy constructor (in the second example) ? surely this contradicts the idea that templates can't be copy constructors?

Comment: Clue: try declaring `const C s1{4};` instead, and see if "everything works" as before. Spoiler: it doesn't.

Comment: A template is never a copy constructor.

Comment: There is no such thing as templatized copy constructor. A copy constructor is never a template. A template is never a copy constructor.

Comment: BTW why exactly is this surprising? In the first case, the best match is a deleted function. In the second case, the best match is a template.

Comment: Think on this, how can you have a copy constructor that copies a different type? That's not really a copy at that point, it's going to be a converting constructor.

Comment: The suggested answer does not answer my question. In that question there is an implicitly generated copy constructor so its not surprising the compiler selects that over the template version. In my code however the    implicitly generated copy constructor has been deleted, so why doesn't it fall back to the templatized constructor?

Comment: @pete becker except, as I explained, the non const template version is a valid copy constructor too and that works...so.in what sense is a template not a copy constructor when in that case it IS being used as one?

Comment: @sam varshavchik that doesn't explain why the const template copy constructor isn't selected when the non template version is deleted

Comment: "the implicitly generated copy constructor has been deleted, so why doesn't it fall back" Because `= delete` doesn't mean "pretend I'm not here". It means "I'm here but don't ever try to call me".

Comment: @horseyguy -- I should have been clearer: I was responding to your phrase "the templatized copy constructor". The C++ standard says that a template is never a copy constructor. That doesn't mean that a template can't be used to construct a copy of an object, just that the special rules for a copy constructor don't apply to a template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just overload resolution. In `C s2{s1};`, you are looking for a constructor of `C` that can take a (non-`const`) `C` lvalue argument. For `template<typename T> C(T const&)`, the "closest" this constructor can get to matching the argument list is setting `T = C`, so you get `C(C const&)` (this solution for `T` is found by template argument deduction, which we don't need to go into). The copy constructor `C(C const&) = delete;` can also be called with this argument list. The two implicit conversion sequences involved (`C` lvalue undergoes identity conversion to bind to `C const&`), are also exactly the same, so neither overload is immediately "better" than the other than the other. However, the `delete`d one is not a template, so it's considered to be better anyway. The `delete`d overload is chosen, causing an error. If you have instead `template<typename T> C(T&)`, then it can get closer to the given argument list, by setting `T = C` to get `C(C&)`. Now, the implicit conversion sequence where a `C` lvalue binds to a `C&` (the case of the template) is better than the implicit conversion sequence where a `C` lvalue binds to a `C const&` (the copy constructor), since there are fewer qualifiers to add, so now the template wins and the code compiles.

Addressing the comments, your templated constructor indeed isn't a copy constructor. [According to cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor),

> A copy constructor of class `T` is a non-template constructor...

Also, you may be misunderstanding what `= delete;` means. `C(C const&) = delete;` does *not* mean "there is *not* an overload with this signature", it means "there is an overload with this signature, and trying to call it is an error". You can't not have a copy constructor as one of the overloads of a class's constructor. `delete`ing it only makes it an error to *use* that overload but doesn't stop overload resolution from picking it over another overload.

Comment: Thanks. What if the copy constructor is just not generated rather than bring explicitly deleted ?I.e via the definition of a copy assignment operator. Or is that equivalent to an = delete?

Comment: @horseyguy A copy constructor is always declared and always participates in overload resolution. Your example is an implicitly `delete`d constructor.

Comment: Thanks. One last question...in what sense isn't the templatized non const constructor not a copy constructor? I know the standard says it had to be non template, but the compiler is still invoking it to make copies of non const instances, so isn't it in all respects functioning as a copy constructor even though its a template?

Comment: If you e.g. didn't declare the copy constructor, then the compiler would not recognize your template as a copy constructor and declare one itself. The form of the copy constructor also controls whether it (and therefore it's class) are considered trivial, etc.

Comment: Thanks @HTNW - i believe many of your answers are non-trivial (such as deleted constructors  still particpating in overload resolution and blocking the templated fall-back) and your clear description of what a copy constructor IS - even though the non-const template constructor appeared to be one. I don't know why this question was marked as duplicate when none of the linked questions address these topics nor have such clear answers. I think many other C++ noobs would find this important/interesting too. Thanks!